# Use of protected media properties in page ressources (TYPO3 8.7.4)

Tags: typo3

I have an image file in the page properties and I can't find a way to use the properties of the file reference because they are all protected.

[image: <f:debug>{data.media}</f:debug>]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not every attribute must be in the debug. If you look into the FileReference class you can see that there are several getters for different fields.

In PHP you do:

```
$title = $myFileReference->getTitle();
$description = $myFileReference->getDescription();
```

In Fluid you do:

```
{fileReference.title}
{fileReference.description}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick helpful answer. I hoped to get the file with {data.media) and I need the crop property.

Answer (score 1):

You can access all properties through `{fileReference.originalResource.properties}`